# bower register new version

Tags: bower, semantic-versioning, bower-register

I register a version of my "angular-backstrech-adrr" to bower:

`bower register angular-backstrech-adrr git@github.com:AladdinMhaimeed/angular-backstrech-adrr.git`

this is bower.json:

```
{
  "author": "Aladdin Mhaimeed",
  "name": "angular-backstrech-adrr",
  "version": "1.0.4",
  "main": "angular-backstretch.js",
  "dependencies": {
          "jquery": ">2.0.0",
          "jquery-backstretch": "https://raw.github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch/master/jquery.backstretch.min.js"
  }
```

}

Bower says it is successfully registered, but when I use:

```
bower info angular-backstretch-adrr
```

It says there is no version available.

If I change the version and try to register again, I get: **EDUPLICATE**

Is there something wrong in the bower.json? Anything wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your package only needs to be registered once. The versions are drawn from your Git tags. From the Bower [documentation](https://github.com/bower/bower):

> Your package must be available at a Git endpoint (e.g., GitHub);
>   remember to push your Git tags!

Not to worry, I had no idea what this meant either. After poking around a bit, I stumbled across [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging).

Here's the quick and easy way to solve your problem... from your project's root directory run:

```
% git tag v1.0.4
```

If you type:

```
% git tag
```

you'll see the version you just created. Now push your Git tags:

```
% git push origin v1.0.4
```

Now when you run `bower info angular-backstretch-adrr`, you'll see the version you just pushed.

Answer (score 7):

Above answer is correct except v in front of version is incorrect.

```
//Incorrect
% git tag v1.0.4

//Correct
% git tag 1.0.4
```

Now push it. Github also complains when try to put v in front of tag.

Live log of bower

```
bower not-cached    git://github.com/speedovation/Inventive.git#*
bower resolve       git://github.com/speedovation/Inventive.git#*
bower download      https://github.com/speedovation/Inventive/archive/0.9.6.tar.gz
bower progress      inventive#* received 0.4MB
bower progress      inventive#* received 0.5MB
```

#### See 0.9.6 in log. If v used it will fail.

Comment: Hi, actually it's also not entirely true :) As stated in [docs](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#version) bower will accept any versioning parseable by [node-semver](https://github.com/npm/node-semver) package. If you'll install it and try `semver v1.0.4` it'll be parsed as `1.0.4`. Actually this worked for me today, when I was submitting new version of my package. This makes @daniel-bidulock answer valid.

Comment: Ok. Although not worked in my case. Also github prefer to without v. So avoiding would be easy and hassle free.